# Using Object Relational Mapping (ORM) on wordpress

Tags: orm, wordpress

I am trying my hand at wordpress and after searching google for a solution,i have come up with nothing.Is it possible to use an ORM with wordpress?.

Comment: Wordpress has its own database wrapper which, as far as I know, is very primitive. At which point would you want to use an ORM? Do you want to replace Wordpress's native method?

Comment: I am not that ambitious,i thought to myself that an ORM can make things a bit easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/doctrine/) that integrates the Doctrine ORM into WP.

Cheers!